Bundling Jupyter Kernel into an exe with PyInstaller?
I am trying to bundle my python application into an executable file using the PyInstaller library.
Part of my application uses KernelManager from the jupyter_client library to start and interact with Jupyter Kernels.
When I build the Python scripts into an application and run the .exe file, I get a host of errors that all boil down to:
RuntimeError: Kernel died before replying to kernel_info
I have looked around on Stack Overflow and other forums to try to see if anyone has had a similar need of bundling a jupyter kernel into a .exe, but the closest thing I could find was this thread asking if a jupyter notebook can be bundled.
Has anyone had experience and success bundling applications that rely on Jupyter Kernels into executable files?
